# Using a string for a pattern in regex using key regex characters

Tags: c#, regex

Edit: To clear confusion this is still unsolved, even with the "nicer looking" Replace function.

So, long story short, I'm creating regexes from file input, the only thing is, the file input for when regexes are needed, will look like this:

```
look*
```

Which, in C#'s regex terms, would mean:

```
look[a-zA-Z]*
```

So, I tried to do that using the following code:

```
static void HighlightPhrase(RichTextBox box, string phrase, Color color)
    {
        int pos = box.SelectionStart;
        MatchCollection myM;
        string s = box.Text;
        MessageBox.Show(phrase, "PHRASE");
        if (phrase.Contains("*"))
        {
            phrase = phrase.Replace(phrase = phrase.Replace("*", "[a-zA-Z]*");
            MessageBox.Show(phrase);
            myM = Regex.Matches(s, phrase);
            foreach (Match m in myM)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("I reach here!");
                box.SelectionStart = m.Index;
                box.SelectionLength = m.Length;
                box.SelectionColor = color;
            }
            box.SelectionStart = pos;
            box.SelectionLength = 0;
        }
```

Ignore the MessageBoxes, those are for debugging purposes, but unfortunately, the "I reach here" box is never seen. My entire objective is to actually achieve successful matches to start that foreach loop.

Comment: Just a comment, but why aren't you using a debugger to debug?

Comment: One more 'just comment', why use a regex to replace `*` to `[a-zA-Z]*`?

Comment: It's simpler to use MessageBoxes, when I've gotten the problem down to a specific segment of code, MessageBoxes just help me out more quickly than sifting through all the variables in the debugger. In response to Aneri, it's just what I know to handle the situation, I've used Perl for so long it's hard for me to not use regex. Either way the issue is using what results from said regex, even though it does actually turn it into the pattern I want.

Comment: Uhh? Phrase is set outside of the function. "PHRASE" is the title of the MessageBox.

Comment: Sample input please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick aside:  You should include some sample input that isn't working for you.  Without sample input, this is just a guess.

You probably need to specify some [RegexOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) for your Matches call; my money is on you wanting a case-insensitive search.

```
myM = Regex.Matches(s, phrase, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: After realizing that was the only thing I needed I am now very sad. Thank you very much though. C#'s Regex life is way different to experience than Perl land.

Answer (score 2):

Don't see you need regex for this simple replace. Use this instead

```
phrase = phrase.Replace("*", "[a-zA-Z]*");
```

Comment: Yes it's simpler, but it doesn't solve the issue. As an edit: I've taken the liberty of putting in the replace, because admittedly it is much nicer to look at.

Comment: @SirLulzalot: what are you trying to match? Words?

Comment: All instances of the word the file has. If that's too ambiguous, I mean all instances of the word, for this example, look* in the file, where * means any alphabetic character after look.